# how use Schema methods in mongoose sub-documents after loading

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following scheme in the mongoose

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CellSchema = new Schema({
    foo: Number,
});

CellSchema.methods.fooMethod= function(){
    return 'hello';
};


var GameSchema = new Schema({
    field: [CellSchema]
});
```

if create new document like:

```
var cell = new CellModel({foo: 2})
var game = new GameModel();
game.field.push(cell);

game.field[0].fooMethod();
```

it's correctly work. But if you run this code:

```
GameModel.findOne({}, function(err, game) {
    console.log(game);
    game.field[0].fooMethod()
})
```

i get TypeError: game.field[0].fooMethod is not a function
and console log is

```
{ 
  field: 
   [ { foo: 2,
       _id: 5675d5474a78f1b40d96226d }
   ]
}
```

how correct load sub-document with all schema methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the methods on the embedded schema before defining the parent schema.

Also you have to reference `CellSchema` instead of `'Cell'`

```
var CellSchema = new Schema({
    foo: Number,
});
CellSchema.methods.fooMethod = function() {
    return 'hello';
};

var GameSchema = new Schema({
    field: [CellSchema]
});
```

Comment: sorry, in my case, it is. I change my example

Comment: `field: [CellSchema]` make sure it isn't a string but a direct reference to the schema

Comment: wow. i fixed it. thanx you for idea. In my first variant code Game and Cell its different modules, where exports its 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cell', CellSchema); That is why I used 'Cell' in my code

Comment: I change cell module to 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cell', CellSchema);
module.exports.CellSchema = CellSchema; and use field: [Cell.CellSchema], in game Schema and it's work. Great! Thanx!